# How to handle dll dependency that may not be present?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an app that has two different implementations of a component.

I only want to load a preferred implementation if the dll is present; if it's not present then I can catch an instantiation exception and choose the fallback implementation.

Here's some psuedocode:

```
internal static IThing CreateInstance()
{
     try
     {
          return new PreferredThing();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          Log("Unable to load preferred thing. Falling back to old thing.");
          return new OldThing();
     }
}
```

I understand it's debatable to always be throwing an exception - for performance reasons and because catch-all exception handlers are bad, but let's assume this is acceptable.

My specific issue is that a `FileNotFoundException` for the `PreferredThing` dll will be thrown before even getting to the body of the `CreateInstance` method. It seems that the runtime is attempting to preload the `PreferredThing` dll immediately at the point that `CreateInstance` is called.

Is there a way to somehow avoid this preload?

**Update**: I removed the term `plugin` from the problem description as it seemed to cause more confusion. It's not really about designing a plugin system. In actuality, the preferred and old thing are complex types that work similarly, but the preferred one works better. I'm not actually allowing arbitrary plugins to be loaded.

Comment: What about actually loading the DLL at runtime via ```Assembly.LoadFile```?

Comment: @Shawn `Assembly.LoadFile` is another way to tell if the PreferredThing dll is present, but I don't see how using this will prevent the preload outside of my exception handler.

Comment: @Daniel Without adding PreferredThing as a project reference, Why not load the assembly using reflection within CreateInstance() and return the instance.

Comment: Is dynamic loading an option? You could use MEF to load plugins...

Comment: @Kurubaran If I use `CreateInstance()` in the code block above, I assume it won't matter, because the exception has already happened earlier.

Comment: `catch (Exception ex)` like that is a bad anti-pattern. Have a read of [Eric Lippert's Vexing Exceptions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/).

Comment: Yep, @Enigmativity, Understood. For the sake of the question, I tried to exclude discussion of the exception catch handling. In this real case, there are multiple dlls and files - that could have been configured incorrectly, so falling back to the `OldThing` when the `PreferredThing` fails to load is also desired.

Comment: That is not how plugins are implemented.  The catch doesn't catch because of the stuff that must happen *before* the code starts running.  The work done by the just-in-time compiler.  It fails in the calling code, you cannot know exactly where.  It is different in the Release build vs the Debug build.  Which is why plugin managers can never skip the "load the assembly first" step.  Never use LoadFile, only Load or LoadFrom.  But don't write it yourself, it has been done before.

Comment: @HansPassant Your comment seems closest to what I am afraid is the right answer. I updated the question to remove the "plugin" characterization as it probably wasn't helpful.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_test